# Get attibute label option for current store

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, labels, option

I have a 'size' attribute with lot of option. For each option, I have translation for each my stores :

[image: size attribute]

I want to get the translation label for a product and for a given store.

So :

I load my product

```
$prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(1)->load($productId);
```

Then I try to get label :

```
$label = $prod->getResource()->getAttribute('size')->getFrontend()->getValue($prod);
```

But I always get the default value : here "TU" (store 0) instead of "Taille Unique" (store 1).

If I try to get the label with this code :

```
$label = $prod->getAttributeText('size');
```

Now, I get "One Size" (store 2) instead of "Taille unique" (store 1) and it's really weird, isn't it ?

What is wrong in my code ?

Comment: What happens if you do `$prod->getData()`?

Comment: That return the data of my product (and the store is egal to 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below code:

```
$prod->getResource()->getAttribute('size')->setStoreId(1)->getFrontend()->getValue($prod);
```

Comment: That return "TU" (store 0) :/

Comment: make sure you can add proper store id in setStoreId()

Comment: What's mean ? I can write "setStoreId()" but then, that don't set the store ?

Comment: Please see in my answer, i wrote setStoreId(1) just for example, you can replaced your store id and this is working fine for me here..thank you

Comment: I use your "setStoreId(1)" but that return me the value of the store 0 (default store)

Comment: you wrote "This is working fine for me" => So, may be I have another error somewhere ? Like cache or index or other ? Because I use the same code as you

Comment: Even if I set a storeId that doesn't exist, that return me the value of the default store :/

Comment: I had made a mistake in another place, but your code works, thanks !